# Updating view using jQuery and CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have one controller containing 2 functions, first one "messages", generates html content of messages that are stored in database. The second function "inbox" contains all the formatting and a div, where i want to include content from "messages" (basically the whole page) and it should be refreshed every 5 seconds.

I tried putting this jQuery code in "inbox"'s view (has `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`):

```
function update() {
  $.get("<?= base_url("index.php/chat/messages") ?>", function(data) {
    $("#output_div").html(data);
    window.setTimeout(update, 1000);
  });
}
```

and placing a div#output_div below it. But it doesn't show any content.

Do you have any suggestions how to make this work? Thank you for advice ;)

EDIT: I figured out what was wrong:

```
$(document).ready(function update() {
      $.get("<?= base_url("index.php/chat/messages") ?>", function(data) {
        $("#output_div").html(data);
        window.setTimeout(update, 1000);
      });
    })
```

Comment: Can you show the rendered code?  I.e. the result of your PHP?

Comment: How do you call the `update()` method?

Comment: @Mischa, that was my next question! Miso, show code please!

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your JS call in quotes, i.e.:

```
window.setTimeout("update", 10000);
```

You might also need the parentheses:  `"update()"`

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help at all. I still get empty divs.